# Neo4j 4.3 - Deprecation of size function and pattern comprehension

Tags: neo4j, cypher

In Neo4j 4.3, I get a deprecation warning for the function `size` with the following text:

```
A pattern expression should only be used in order to test the existence of a pattern. It should therefore only be used in contexts that evaluate to a boolean, e.g. inside the function exists() or in a WHERE-clause. All other uses are deprecated and should be replaced by a pattern comprehension.
```

and I have this query:

```
MATCH (user:User {id: "ffca99b2-0842-491d-b51f-b7c76109e355"})
RETURN user, 
       size((user)-[:FOLLOWS]->(:User)) as numberOfFollowing // This is deprecated
```

I found a way to make it work without the deprecation that I find quite uglier than the previous one.

```
MATCH (user:User {id: "ffca99b2-0842-491d-b51f-b7c76109e355"})
RETURN user, 
       size([(user)-[:FOLLOWS]->(other:User) | user]) as numberOfFollowing // No more deprecation
```

My question is: Is that the only way to get the size of a pattern anymore, or is there a better way? I haven't found any documentation about it, and the official documentation does not say that `size` is deprecated: https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/scalar/#functions-size-of-pattern-expression

Answer (score 0):

I think `SIZE(COLLECT (other))`  also works

The new syntax offers a lot more possibilities, because you can combine it with `WHERE` clause and you can also avoid `OPTIONAL MATCH` in many cases.

Comment: Yes, this one would work as well. But it would require to do an optional match first and aggregate. I still prefer the way I showed personally, but it's possible that it's the only way available now.

Answer (score 0):

Use this function below:

```
length()
```

It is a replacement for size() exclusively for paths.

```
 Quote: No longer works for paths. Only works for strings, lists and pattern expressions.
```

Reference: https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/deprecations-additions-removals-compatibility/#cypher-deprecations-additions-removals-4.0

Comment: Well that's interesting. I did not see that, but it surprisingly still work up to 4.3.

Comment: The function size() still works but not to path anymore. It will work on list like what you did. Great job.

Comment: Use length() instead of size() when working with paths. Thanks.

Comment: I did not know about this function. Thanks! But weirdly, it does not work the way size used to work

This works
```
match (p:Person) 
return p, size((p)-[:HAS_ACCOUNT]->(:Account)) LIMIT 10
```

While this doesn't 
```
match (p:Person) 
return p, length((p)-[:HAS_ACCOUNT]->(:Account)) LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer in the [documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/deprecations-additions-removals-compatibility/) is pretty clear.

For the newest versions of neo4j the query should be

```
MATCH (user:User {id: "ffca99b2-0842-491d-b51f-b7c76109e355"})
RETURN user, 
       COUNT { (user)-[:FOLLOWS]->(:User) } as numberOfFollowing
```

I had the same deprecation warning when going through this [training project](https://graphacademy.neo4j.com/courses/app-nodejs/0-setup/), and the use of `COUNT { }` solved the issue.